# printing items in a list with a for loop

Tags: c#

I want to build tab-delimited string of shopping cart content. I cycle through a list using a for loop so that items in the cart are meant to be outputted however, only the last item in that list is outputted.

```
public string Display()
{
    CartClass CartList = CartClass.GetCart();
    String display = "" ;

    for (int i = 0; i < CartList.CartList.Count(); i++)
    {
        Movies Movie = CartList.CartList[i];
        display = String.Format(i + 1 + "." + "\t" + 
           Movie.MovieName + "\t" + "£" + Movie.MovieCost.ToString());
    }
    return display;
}
```

how can I solve this?

Side note: ultimately I'll use it to display on web page, but at this point I want to understand why it does not return text for all items.

Comment: @Habib - actually none of the answers saying use "repeater for WebForms" or "render data in an ASP.Net MVC  view immediately instead of trying to collect into variable"....

Comment: Lemons - consider removing "web site" part from this question so answers actually make sense.

Comment: "web forms" is just one option in ASP.Net to create "web site" (in broad meaning as "something that serves HTML pages to browser")... so I don't think your edit actually make question not to refer to HTML. See if you agree with my edit - feel free to revert.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You only see the last because you're doing assignment in each loop iteration. You need to do `+=` instead of `=`.

```
public string Display()
{
    CartClass CartList = CartClass.GetCart();
    String display = "" ;

    for (int i = 0; i < CartList.CartList.Count(); i++)
    {
        Movies Movie = CartList.CartList[i];
        display += String.Format(i + 1 + "." + "\t" + 
            Movie.MovieName + "\t" + "£" + Movie.MovieCost.ToString()) + "\n";
    }
    return display;
}
```

Note that it is generally better to use `StringBuilder` for building large strings.

Comment: Many thanks! I've never come across a += before and that solution works a treat!

Comment: +0: while generally correct, notice " trying to create a website" part - clearly building formatted HTML with string concatenation / `\t` is not the right approach.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov , Hi, what is the right approach to create a tab space? and a new line?

Comment: @Lemons code in this answer indeed creates string with tab (and `\n` or [Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx) for new line)."web site" randomly) How it is displayed in HTML is somewhat unrelated to your string formatting as HTML collapses all white spaces into single space (unless you style it not to). You may read something about HTML if it is the case and ask separate question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I've corrected "website" to "web form" if that makes it more appropriate. And I will read up on white spaces. many thanks

Comment: +1. I've changed question to make it match the answers... and added new line and note on string builder - feel free to revert my changes if disagree.

Comment: +1 for stringbuilder. @AlexeiLevenkov you should probably even add the code example using it.

Answer (score 8):

You really should be using a `StringBuilder` here:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < CartList.CartList.Count(); i++)
{
    Movies Movie = CartList.CartList[i];
    sb.Append( String.Format(i + 1 + "." + "\t" + Movie.MovieName + "\t" + "£" + Movie.MovieCost.ToString()));
}
return sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using = sign to set Display text you need to use += or the string builder class.

Answer (score 3):

As already other answers pointed out that you need to append the String using Concatnation operator `+`,I Would like to suggest you to use `StringBuilder`.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < CartList.CartList.Count(); i++)
    {
        Movies Movie = CartList.CartList[i];
        sb .Append(String.Format(i + 1 + "." + "\t" + Movie.MovieName + "\t" + "£" + Movie.MovieCost.ToString());
    }
    return sb.ToString();
```

Comment: change your return value to `sb.ToString()`

Answer (score 2):

You are replacing the value of your variable with the next item in the loop... try adding it.

```
display += String.Format(i + 1 + "." + "\t" + Movie.MovieName + "\t" + "£" + Movie.MovieCost.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

You are overriding the display variable. Try to concat `+=`

Answer (score 2):

You need to concatenate each entry to display as follows (notice `+=`):

```
public string Display()
{
    CartClass CartList = CartClass.GetCart();
    String display = "" ;

    for (int i = 0; i < CartList.CartList.Count(); i++)
    {
        Movies Movie = CartList.CartList[i];
        display += String.Format(i + 1 + "." + "\t" + Movie.MovieName + "\t" + "£" + Movie.MovieCost.ToString());

    }
    return display;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting `display` in each loop.

The simplest change is to change `=` to `+=`  :

```
    //      V-----
    display += String.Format(i + 1 + "." + "\t" + Movie.MovieName + "\t" + "£" + Movie.MovieCost.ToString());
```

But you may find `StringBuilder` more performant if you have a LOT of strings.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this.

```
public string Display()
{
CartClass CartList = CartClass.GetCart();
String display = "" ;

for (int i = 0; i < CartList.CartList.Count(); i++)
{
    Movies Movie = CartList.CartList[i];
    display += String.Format(i + 1 + "." + "\t" + Movie.MovieName + "\t" + "£" + Movie.MovieCost.ToString());
}
return display;
}
```